# cancel onClick javascript functions with another javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI there,

this is a little sticky situation and I need some advice.

I have a couple of href's like this, across my project.

```
<a class="not-allowed" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showSettingDiv();">Change</a>
<a class="" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="DeleteSettingDiv();">Delete</a>
```

Depending on the type of user logged in, I have to have some links do nothing and trigger something else.

I have this function to make that happen:

```
$('.not-allowed').each(function (e) {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("you dont have permission");
     })
 });
```

This does fire up the alert, however, it also executes my onclick function too. is there a way I Can stop all javascript functions and execute just this above one?

I realized I could just use `.removeAttr()` but I am not sure if thats the best way. I mean I might have buttons to restrict or checkbox and radio button to disable.

`e.preventDefault` will not take care of all that I guess. Anyway, How do I prevent all javascript functions ?

Thanks.

Comment: The only way to prevent the `onclick` function to fire is to remove it.

Comment: What happens if someone looks at the page source, sees what the onclick attribute was at page load time, and just punches that url/function call into the address bar? They'll have bypassed your security system and call the function anyways.

Comment: @Marc B - server side validation is already taken care of. Infact, the url would be "javascript:void(0)" if the css class is "not-allowed". In case someone remembers it form the time it was allowed, (say, book mark) that redirects them to different page, if its button click, redirects them to forbidden page etc. I am just trying to make it look user friendly with qTip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is called [Capture mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Registration-interfaces). It works on DOM-compatible browsers. Check out if your JS framework makes this function available for you.

> If the capturing EventListener wishes to prevent further processing of the event from occurring it may call the stopProgagation method of the Event interface.

A quick example:

```
<html>
<body>
    <button class="not-allowed" id="btn1" onclick="alert('onclick executed');">BTN1</button>
    <button id="btn2" onclick="alert('onclick executed');">BTN2</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        if (event.target.className.indexOf("not-allowed") > -1) {
            event.stopPropagation();    // prevent normal event handler form running
            event.preventDefault();    // prevent browser action (for links)
        }
    }, true);
</script>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Not sure this is helping at all. Capturing applies to the DOM tree, not the event listeners of a single event unless I've missed something?

Comment: If you install a listener with `useCapture` then it will be run before any other listeners. I you cancel your event in it, no other (normal mode) listeners will be executed, and that is what the poster wants.

Comment: ... and as I said earlier, check how your framework makes this function avalable in its API.

Comment: excellent example. the buttons all worked, after I tweaked them to my application a bit, but, the href is still taking user to places. I guess I should use jquery and remove the href attribute for this situation? see an example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/byS22/1/

Comment: I understood you just want to cancel other event hadlers. Iy you want to prevent links form doing their linkstuff just add: `event.preventDefault();`. I modified the example accordingly.

Comment: excellenté! thanks so much. this works perfectly, thanks for patiently responding too. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

`.preventDefault()` does not have an affect on *inline event handlers*. You would need to remove the functionality completely. Give this a shot:

```
$('.not-allowed').each(function(i, elem) {
    elem.onclick = null; 
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("you dont have permission");
     })
});
```

Simplified example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cJcCJ/

Comment: hi, what if I have another un-obtrusive function for a class, like `('.doubleCheck').click(return(confirm("are you sure?")));` so in this case, if a link has both these classes, its showing confirm AND alert, both. how would I block this?

Comment: also, on jsfiddle, if I comment your, this line: `//this.onclick = null; ` the rest behaves exactly the same way as it does with that line un-commented. So I dont know what is happening there.

Comment: waited for 3 whole days, no response on my feedback, PLUS your `elem.onclick` doesnt do anything special that the `e.preventDefault` doesn't. esp in this example, its not doing ANYTHING. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the `click` event on a parent element and then bind another click event on the "inactive" elements which will call `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent the event from bubbling up to the parent element.

Another solution would be giving the disabled elements a class and doing `if($(this).hasClass('disabled')) return;` in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have to modify the function(s) in `onclick` (`showSettingDiv`, `DeleteSettingDiv`) to check for the permissions, too.

BTW, make sure that you don't only check permissions in JavaScript, you must also do it server-side, or it's very easy to manipulate.